# Invariant Violation: @react-native-community/cookies: Add RNCookieManagerIOS.h and RNCookieManagerIOS.m to your Xcode project

Tags: react-native, react-native-cookies

I am receiving this error when running `yarn test` in my react native project after installing and importing `@react-native-cookies/cookies`

```
 Invariant Violation: @react-native-community/cookies: Add RNCookieManagerIOS.h and RNCookieManagerIOS.m to your Xcode project
```

The import:

```
import CookieManager from '@react-native-cookies/cookies';
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking it helped:

```
// __mocks__/@react-native-cookies/cookies.ts

const CookieManager = {
  set: jest.fn(),
  get: jest.fn(),
  clearAll: async () => {},
};

export default CookieManager;
```

You can also refer to [this official issue](https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies/issues/136) for more info.